# Derivative of the Selberg $\zeta$-function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, zeta-functions

I want to compute the derivative of the Selberg $\zeta$-function:

$$ \mathcal{Z}(s)=\prod_{\gamma \; \text{primitive}} \prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-e^{-l(\gamma)(n+s)}); \qquad \Re(s)>1.$$

Where $\gamma$ are primitive closed geodesics on a given manifold and $l(\gamma)$ is their lenght. We can assume $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Observe that the given expression is justified by: $l(\gamma^n)= n l(\gamma)$.

A couple of reliable articles ([Lou's "On the zeros of the derivative of the Selberg Zeta function"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40068004?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101130298393) page 1143 for the statement and page 1141 for its definition of $\mathcal{Z}(s)$, and [D'Hoker&Phong's "The geometry of String Perturbation theory](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1988RvMP...60..917D), implicitly in the last passage of page 1005), and  give, more or less explicitly, the following formula for the logarithmic derivative:

$$ \frac{\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{Z}(s)}{\mathcal{Z}(s)} = \sum_{\gamma \; \text{primitive}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{l(\gamma) e^{-l(\gamma)ns}}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)n}}.$$

But my computation seems to give a slightly different result. Indeed, first we observe:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\prod_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\right)= \left(\prod_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)}{f_n(x)}\right).$$

> Is it true? Wikipedia confirms it only in the finite case.

Then, applying it to $ \mathcal{Z}(s)$, I deduce:

$$ \frac{\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{Z}(s)}{\mathcal{Z}(s)} = \sum_{\gamma \; \text{primitive}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{l(\gamma) e^{-l(\gamma)(n+s)}}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)(n+s)}}.$$

> This expression seems to be close to the claimed one but I couldn't
>   prove they are the same. So I guess I'm doing something wrong in the
>   computation. Do you know how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm going to link them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

Write
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)n}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-l(\gamma)kn} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)}}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)}}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)n}.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-l(\gamma)ns}}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)n}} & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-l(\gamma)ns} e^{-l(\gamma)kn} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)n} \\&
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)}}{1-e^{-l(\gamma)(k+s)}}
\end{align*}
$$
multiply by $l(\gamma)$ and sum over the primitives and you seem to get what you want.

Comment: Perfect! 'sorry for the delay in the answer and thank you very much! :)